# Do we know more details about Tamar's life after she was raped by Amnon?

Tags: king-david

What was Tamar's life after she was raped?

Comment: About which Tamar we are talking about? I know at least two of them, but just one of them was raped. Could you please add, where can we read about this event? Why do you think the further events in her life may be relevant?

Comment: @Kazibácsi she mentions Amnon in the question so she is referring to the daughter of Dovid

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the Gemara in [Sanhedrin 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.21a.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> The verse relates that after Amnon raped her: “And Tamar put ashes on her head and rent her garment of many colors that was on her” ([II Samuel 13:19](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.13.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). The Sages taught in the name of Rabbi Yehoshua ben Korḥa: Tamar established a great fence at that time by way of her public outcry, as people said: If such an occurrence could happen to the daughters of kings, all the more so could it happen to the daughters of ordinary people. If such an occurrence could happen to modest women like Tamar, who resisted, all the more so could it happen to licentious women. Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: At that time they decreed about seclusion, that a man should not be secluded with women who are forbidden to him, and about a single woman. (Sefaria translation and notation)

So whilst we don't necessarily know how her life was post the event it at least initiated change. As [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.21b?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.21a.24.1&lang2=bi) asserts:

> With her tears and cries and driving herself in disgrace she (lit.) carried the other women through a 'kal vachomer' (a fortiori) - i.e. if this disgrace is what happens with the daughters of kings, how much more so with the simple/common women.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for info on her personal life. Did she get married at all? do we know anything?

Comment: @Sarah You should (have) be(en) more [specific](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question. Please consider editing it, Dov might be so nice to look it up for you.